# T-SQL Select - Over clause equivalent LINQ Extension

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, distinct, partition

I need to write an extension method for LINQ on C# which implements following scheme.

A generic extension method which implements over (partition by columnName1 ORDER BY columnName2 DESC).

I mean want to be able to implement same logic with same keyword on c# . Not with different way same result.

```
...ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY columnName1 ORDER BY columnName2 DESC) ....
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. If `Row_number` is the problem there are previous questions answering the matter

Comment: You can use `Skip`, `Take` extension methods, you just have to write query in little different way but those will do it.